# Messed up css animations

Tags: css

When creating an animation I positioned the pictures and what not using pixels. I then found out that even if it looks fine my screen, different screens will make it look off. Now my question is; is there any way for me to easily change the pixels to percentage instead, where the animations will appear on the same spot as they used to with pixels?

Comment: If you can post some code so we can help figured it out

Comment: You can try to adjust animations for different screens using media queries

Answer (score 0):

You can't just convert pixels into percentage. But what you can do is make an approximation of the position of the elements that are to be displayed and what size in either percentage (%) or vw (for width) and vh (for height).

Using vw and vh i.e viewport width and viewport height, lets you align the content depending on the actual screen size of the viewport that isn't device dependant. 
So, for example:

`margin-left: 50vw;`  represents a margin from the left which is half of the viewport that is your browser at the current size (even if resized).

It's an absolute positioning criteria in contrast to pixels or em which are for absolute measurements.

You can see the example below demonstrated:

```css
div{
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  background: gray;
  margin: 2em 2em 2em 2em;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
}
#a{
  margin-left:400px;
}
#b{
  margin-left:40%;
}
#c{
  margin-left:40vw;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">A</div>
<div id="b">B</div>
<div id="c">C</div>
```

Open the snippet in full page & resize your browser to see how the position changes of the div containers.

Answer (score 0):

It still may not look right even if you convert pixel to percent as bits might be missing.

To get the percentage you would have to take value of each individual column and image widths and divide by the overall width and multiply by 100.

Example say you have a webpage 1000px wide and 2 images positioned at x=20px with width 150px and another positions at x=190px and width=300px. This would give you a gap of 510px to the right of image 2.

With percentages the new x position of image 1 would be (20/1000)*100 = 2%.  The width of image 1 would be (150/1000)*100=15%.  The x position of image 2 would be (190/1000)*100 = 19% and the width would be (300/1000)*100=30%. The gap to the right would be 51%.